# jquery decode json object with double quoted keys

Tags: getjson, json

I have a script that outputs a json string via json_encode in PHP.  The json string consists of

```
[{"custId":"2","custName":"John Inc"}]
```

The PHP script is initiated using

```
$.getJSON("customer.php", function(data){alert(data + '  ' + data.custName);});
```

The response is -

```
[object Object] undefined
```

Javascript recognises 'data' as an object but I cannot seem to reference the information using json dotted notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` object is in an array so you need to access its elements keyed by an index:

```
alert(data[0].custName);
```

Also, I'd suggest installing [firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) (assuming you are already using Firefox) and using `console.log` in lieu of `alert.`  Its output is much more detailed and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for you response.

Yes that makes sense now.

Cheers